# Why is the major product of the reaction of 1-naphtol with benzene diazonium chloride not the ortho product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, regioselectivity

If 1-napthol reacts with benzene diazonium chloride, it gives the para product with respect to the hydroxyl group. However, shouldn't the major product be the ortho one, because there will be intramolecular $\ce{H}$-bonding between the $\ce{H}$ atom and $\ce{N}$?

Answer (score 1):

When benzene diazonium chloride attacks the ortho position with respect to -OH it(the benzene ring) experiences a lot of steric hindrances,along with that,the triple bond also repels the lone pairs of oxygen,therefore the nitrogen atom will attack para with respect to the -OH group.If the temperature is increased i think that an ortho product will be formed as it is the thermodynamicly stable product,while the para product is the kinetically stable product.